# Apk file build using buildozer closes as soon as i open it

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I try to make a simple hello world app for android using python, kivy and buildozer.

my hello.py file is

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label
class Hello2App(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label()
if __name__=="__main__":
    Hello2App().run()
```

My hello.kv file

```
<Label>:
text: 'Hello World!'
```

I use buildozer in ubuntu to compile apk.
Sudo buildozer android debug deploy

do i need to apply looping like we do in pygame and Tkinter to show gui or window

Comment: Did you enable Kivy in your buildozer spec? What commands did you run?

Comment: sudo android debug deploy

Comment: Did you mean `buildozer android debug deploy`? Try using `android_new` instead of `android`

Answer (score 2):

Your Python script must be named main.py. If you check the error that you are getting it would read something like "Unable to find main.py". Just try renaming the file from hello.py to main.py and build again.

Comment: Done. but still same result.

Comment: Try using this command instead to see what error you get exactly. `buildozer android debug deploy run logcat`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your error by changing `main.py`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder


class Hello2App(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("hello.kv")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Hello2App().run()
```

`hello.kv`:

```
Label:
    text: 'Hello World!'
```

Now you just need to type `buildozer init` and `buildozer android debug` and you are ready to go.